Howe - Moore theorem & Horocycle flow.
I have been studying independently the Howe Moore theorem from the translation surface book by Jayadev & Masur, here is the picture of it:

But I do not understand the importance of each condition in the theorem and why the horocycle flow is an immediate consequence of it, can someone explain this to me or at least direct me to a detailed notes about this part, preferably with solved problems on this part so that I can feel every specific detail and condition in it.
